# NodeJS Request handler

Tags: node.js

I have some issues with a server that does not support IPv6 requests from Apple Application Review. So they reject my update.

And i'm thinking of making a request handler as a middle server, with nodejs.

So my app will send the requests in my new server, which server will send the request to the old server, take the response json back, and serve it back as well in my app.

So lets say the old webserver request was the following

```
https://www.example.com/example/api/index.php?action=categories&subaction=getproducts&category_id=100304&limit=0,30
```

But the request parameters are not always the same!
It may vary but the main URL is always the same

```
https://www.example.com/example/api/index.php?
```

The question is how to get the request params dynamically, make a request to the old webserver and return the response to the request of the new webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a very simple proxy like this;

```
const express = require('express')
const request = require('request')

const app = express()
const BASE_URL = 'http://www.google.com' // change accordingly

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  request({ 
    url: BASE_URL + req.originalUrl 
  }).pipe(res)
})

app.listen(8900, () => console.log('Listening...'))
```

[req.originalUrl](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req.originalUrl) will allow to concatenate the path + the query string to your base url

Comment: works as a charm! the whole point i guess was the `req.originalUrl` !